# foundation5/css - disable/reset a css property

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am working with foundation and trying to convert an Image to a working HTML. Sorry but I am using foundation for the first time. But my question is and isn't much related to only.
Here is the thing. In foundation, when you use "block-grids", foundation applies some paddings to the li elements. Take a look no the following image.

[image]

I have done this by assign a class "last" to these three li elements and have used

```
padding-bottom:0px;
```

for this class to get desired results.

Now, when I get into the mobile view, I get the following result due to the above class.

[image]

Now, I know the workarounds that I can use media query and assign some padding to the class "last" or I can use jQuery to remove that class from small devices. But that way, foundation won't be the one applying that padding automatically. But if I disable this property, then foundation will take care of the padding. Is that possible? With CSS only?

Answer (score 0):

For situations like this you, as you hinted at, media queries is the tool you are looking for - which technically is only CSS.

Foundation is a framework, and has its default styling, but they can't make their styles work for everybody/every project out of the box, as you have found in your case.

As an avid user of foundation, there are many examples, like the one above, where you have to write a bit of custom CSS.

I would implement either of the following:

1. Only use padding-top for block grid elements, I think eliminating your issue here.

   ```
   $block-grid-elements: 12;
   $block-grid-default-spacing: 0; // set this to 0, and then manually reset it to just be left-right-bottom padding.
   $align-block-grid-to-grid: true;


   // Somewhere in your foundation overrides css file.
   ul.block-grid {
       padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
   }
   ```
2. Otherwise, keep the default padding and write some media query code:

   ```
   <ul>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li class="last-large"></li>
   <li class="last-large last-small"></li>
   <li class="last-large last-small"></li>
   </ul>


   @media #{$small-only} {
       .last-small {
           padding-bottom: 0;    
       }
   }

   @media #{$medium-up} {
       .last-large {
           padding-bottom: 0;    
       }
   }
   ```